# What's the best way to create datetime from "%H:%M:%S"

Tags: python, datetime

Say I got some string with format `%H:%M:%S`, e.g. `04:35:45`. I want to convert them to `datetime.datetime` object, year/month/day are the same as `datetime.datetime.now()`.

I tried

```
now = datetime.now()
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%H:%M:%S")
datetime_obj.year = now.year
datetime_obj.month = now.month
datetime_obj.day = now.day
```

This won't work since `year/month/day` are read-only properties. So what's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `datetime.combine(date, time)`:

```
>>> time = datetime.datetime.strptime("04:35:45", "%H:%M:%S").time()
>>> time
datetime.time(4, 35, 45)
>>> day = datetime.datetime.now().date()
>>> day
datetime.date(2016, 1, 6)
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(day, time)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 6, 4, 35, 45)
>>>
```

Comment: Personally I prefer this answer.

Answer (score 4):

A third-party [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) uses the current date in this case:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse  
>>> time_string = "04:35:45"
>>> parse(time_string)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 6, 4, 35, 45)
```

---

Or, you can use [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to set the year, month and day:

```
>>> datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%H:%M:%S")
>>> datetime_obj.replace(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 6, 4, 35, 45)
```

Though, I really like the [`.combine()` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637424/771848) posted by Bruno.

Comment: Good. Can I do it without 3rd-party lib?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetime_obj.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace). From the docs:

> Return a datetime with the same attributes, except for those attributes given new values by whichever keyword arguments are specified.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_string = "04:35:45"

now = datetime.now()
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%H:%M:%S")
datetime_obj = datetime_obj.replace(
        year = now.year,
        month = now.month,
        day = now.day
        )

print datetime_obj
```

which prints:

```
2016-01-06 04:35:45
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the time as ints to `datetime.replace` without needing to create two datetime objects:

```
time_sring = "12:31:33"
hr, mn, sec = map(int, time_sring.split(":"))
dtetime_obj = datetime.now().replace( hour=hr, minute=mn, second=sec)
2016-01-06 12:31:33.439492
```